# Best way to classify labeled sentences from a set of documents

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, nltk

I have a classification problem and I need to figure out the best approach to solve it.  I have a set of training documents, where some the sentences and/or paragraphs within the documents are labeled with some tags.  Not all sentences/paragraphs are labeled. A sentence or paragraph may have more than one tag/label.  What I want to do is make some model, where given a new documents, it will give me suggested labels for each of the sentences/paragraphs within the document.  Ideally, it would only give me high-probability suggestions.

If I use something like nltk NaiveBayesClassifier, it gives poor results, I think because it does not take into account the "unlabeled" sentences from the training documents, which will contain many similar words and phrases as the labeled sentences.  The documents are legal/financial in nature and are filled with legal/financial jargon most of which should be discounted in the classification model.

Is there some better classification algorithm that Naive Bayes, or is there some way to push the unlabelled data into naive bayes, in addition to the labelled data from the training set?

Comment: Can you provide a rough estimate for how much of the data is labeled and how much is not. As NBC is a probabilistic model it might be biased towards the data which is in much abundance.

Comment: how much data do you have? you will likely need data at least in the thousands for best classification.

Comment: also, have you looked at [Chapter 6 of the NLTK book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html)? they talk about decision trees and the maximum entropy model on top of Naive Bayes. SVMs may also be worth taking a look at - you can access them and other classification methods through the nltk.classify package, which is a [wrapper](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify.scikitlearn) around the [scikit-learn library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'd do to slightly modify your existing approach: train a single classifier for each possible tag, for each sentence. Include all sentences not expressing that tag as *negative* examples for the tag (this will implicitly count unlabelled examples). For a new test sentence, run all n classifiers, and retain classes scoring above some threshold as the labels for the new sentence.

I'd probably use something other than Naive Bayes. Logistic regression (MaxEnt) is the obvious choice if you want something probabilistic: SVMs are very strong if you don't care about probabilities (and I don't think you do at the moment).

This is really a sequence labelling task, and ideally you'd fold in predictions from nearby sentences too... but as far as I know, there's no principled extension to CRFs/StructSVM or other sequence tagging approaches that lets instances have multiple labels.

Answer (score 1):

> is there some way to push the unlabelled data into naive bayes

There is no distinction between "labeled" and "unlabeled" data, Naive Bayes builds simple conditional probabilities, in particular `P(label|attributes)` and `P(no label|attributes)` so it is heavily based on used processing pipeline but I highly doubt that it actually ignores the unlabelled parts. If it does so for some reason, and you do not want to modify the code, you can also introduce some artificial label "no label" to all remaining text segments.

> Is there some better classification algorithm that Naive Bayes

Yes, NB is in fact the most basic model, and there are dozens better (stronger, more general) ones, which achieve better results in text tagging, including:

- Hidden Markov Models (HMM)
- Conditional Random Fields (CRF)
- in general -Probabilistic Graphical Models (PGM)

Comment: HMMs and CRFs won't be able to deal with the multi-label aspect of this problem, though. In fact it's hard to think of how to do this as sequence labelling and retain that aspect

Comment: @BenAllison Actually he can train one CRF model per label, as long as there are not thousands of labels it should work well.

Comment: It will work, I'm not sure about work well. One CRF per label will mean you lose interactions between labels in subsequent timesteps, which is rather the point of the CRF in the first place... unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean?